# python formatting http requests

Tags: json, python-3.x, post, httprequest

Im trying to send out a POST request using AWS. My issue is that I keep getting Error 400: Bad request. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
url = 'https://api.samanage.com/incidents.json' # Set destination URL here
post_fields = {
    'incident': {
        'name': 'practice tickets for alexa',
        'priority': 'LOW',
        'requester': {
            'email': 'example@samanage.com'
        }
    }
}     # Set POST fields here

headers = {
    'cookie': 'rbzid=OquMLWfcbKxn7DHPYXDBAb6%2Bg%2FS7%2FMkG5RPBxCSy5tRDToqbLchk3q4HUPyH%2FFJ1ykIrbT7gAhVigPk9n8dmrt%2BxzZwOnF5g9Gby2ljY%2FGk%3D',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'x-samanage-authorization': 'Bearer **Token**',
    'accept': 'application/vnd.samanage.v2.1+json'
}

request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode(), headers=headers)
json = urlopen(request).read().decode()
print(json)
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that if I take the headers out completely then I get a 401 Unauthorized error code

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this isn't possible in the AWS in line text editor. I had to download the AWS CLI and create lambda function from the CLI